# How to connect flex3 application to Database with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, apache-flex, flex3

I am beginner to Flex3 .. I am developing simple application with login screen having fields user name and password. I wanted to know how i store this information in MySql database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are all kinds of examples out there already to help you with this. As an aside, if you're just getting started in Flex, I'd start with Flex 4. Here's a few examples:

- [Flex 3 / PHP / MySQL Client/Server Application](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JiwN1PsrhHc)
- [Simple MySQL to Flex](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Simple_MySQL_to_Flex-5561.html)